# Access applications which are hosted on windows ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

How do I enable client users to access an application directly from their devices from anywhere which runs on Windows EC2 Server?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the inputs from the question here are few directions.

First of all the enabling of the access majorly depends upon the type of application and its nature. The below question aims at providing more like a RD [ Remote Desktop ] Access to the EC2 instance from mobile devices.

Here are the following things you can do

- Install Remote Desktop App for tables and access the instance via the app
- iPad [ https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id714464092?mt=8 ]
- Android Tablet [ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android ]

---

- Set Up Amazon Workspaces and access the instance via the app
- iPad [ https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazon-workspaces/id727778113?mt=8 ]
- Android [ https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.workspaces